# apps error in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and I've started to develop an app in android studio. In Gradle it's telling that BUILD SUCCESSFUL. It crashes when it lunches in the mobile device and providing the following error in 'logcat'.

I tried to understand the error message, but it doesn't make much sense to me. Any idea how to approach this problem? It was fine before and app lunches properly. I have four java files which are provided after the error message.

```
 08-28 16:09:06.645  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
 08-28 16:09:06.653  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
 08-28 16:09:06.661  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
 08-28 16:09:06.723  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
 08-28 16:09:07.309  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
 08-28 16:09:07.309  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41840700)
 08-28 16:09:07.340  15906-15906/com.example.uadmin.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.uadmin.weatherapp;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.SharedPreferences;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_map) {
        openPreferredLocationInMap();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  private void openPreferredLocationInMap() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String location = sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),   getString(R.string.pref_location_default));

    // Using the URI scheme for showing a location found on a map. This super-handy
    // intent can is detailed in the "Common Intents" page of Android's developer site:
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

    Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("q", location)
            .build();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(geoLocation);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // if the map apps is not in the phone
    else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't call " + location + ", no receiving apps installed!");
    }

    }
    }

  ForecastFragment.java
   ---------------------

  package com.example.uadmin.weatherapp;

  import android.content.SharedPreferences;
  import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import java.net.URL; 
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.text.*;

  /*
   Encapsulates fetching the forecast and displaying it as a {@link ListView} layout.
      */

  public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

   private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
   public ForecastFragment() { }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateWeather();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*
    // Create some dummy data for the ListView. Here's a sample weekly forecast
    String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };

    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
    */

    // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.

    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    new ArrayList<String>());

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
    }

    private void updateWeather() {

    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String location = prefs.getString(
            getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
            getString(R.string.pref_location_default)
    );
    weatherTask.execute(location);
    // weatherTask.execute("94026");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      updateWeather();
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask< String, Void, String[] > {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
       The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
       so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
    */

    private String getReadableDateString(long time){

        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
        return format.format(date).toString();
    }

    /*
      Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
    */

    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {

        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
         SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String unitType = sharedPrefs.getString(
                getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_units_metric)
        );

        // conversion formula :  [°C  x  9/5 + 32 = °F]
        if (unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial))){
            high = (high*1.8) + 32;
            low = (low*1.8) +32;
        }

        else if ( !unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_metric))){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unit type not found :" + unitType );
        }

        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow =  Math.round(low);
        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
        }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy: constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */

    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {
        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.

        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);
        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];

        for( int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++ ) {

            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long. We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".

            long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp". Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature. It confuses everybody.

            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);
            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
           }
          return resultStrs;
         }

      @Override
      protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up. Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;

        try {

        // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
        // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
        // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        }

        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // New data is back from the server. Hooray!
        }
       }

     }
   }

  DetailActivity.java
  -------------------


  package com.example.uadmin.weatherapp;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                .commit();
    }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    // values -> strings
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent( this, SettingsActivity.class ));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }



    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #WeatherApp";
    private String mForecastStr;

    public DetailFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        // The detail Activity called via intent. Inspect the intent for forecast data.
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                    .setText(mForecastStr);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);
        // Retrieve the share menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

        // Attach an intent to this ShareActionProvider. You can update this at any time,
        // like when the user selects a new piece of data they might like to share.
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }

        else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
        }
    }

    private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
        return shareIntent;
    }

    }
    }



    SettingsActivity.java 
    ---------------------


    package com.example.uadmin.weatherapp;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.media.Ringtone;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.ListPreference;
    import android.preference.Preference;
    import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
    import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
    import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
    import java.util.List;


    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key)));
    }


    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {

    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(
            preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), "")
    );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {

    String stringValue = value.toString();
    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
      }

    else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
      }

      return true;
    }

    }
```

Comment: post your arrayadapter and your activity class

Comment: I think your Array is null, did you initialize it? I mean, the array you are using in your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: can you add more code?